# What is the use of Mov ah,10 in int 21h

Tags: assembly, nasm, dos, x86-16

What is the use of `mov ah,10` in `int 21h`

Mostly we use like `mov ah,0a` for string input but why mov ah,10?

```
nter db 'enter you name:$'
nam db 50,0,50 dup('$')     ;num is 50, num + 1 is 0, num + 2 is 50
lfcr db 10,13,'$'           ;line feed carrier return/next line carriage return
.code
main proc 
    mov ax,@data            ;define
    mov ds,ax
    mov ah,9                
    lea dx,nter             ;output nter
    int 21h
    mov ah,10
    lea dx,nam
    int 21h
```

Comment: `0Ah` (hex) is `10` decimal.

Comment: The value 10 decimal is the same as 0a hexadecimal. Two ways of expressing the same number

Answer (score 3):

> Mostly we use like mov ah,0a for string input but why mov ah,10?

You could use decimal if you want; but most (all?) reference material for DOS functions show values (for function numbers, interrupt numbers and addresses) in hexadecimal and other programmers are more likely to recognize the hexadecimal values; so using decimal will make it harder to read.

The other alternative is to use the pre-processor - e.g. maybe "`#define BUFFERED_INPUT_FUNCTION_NUMBER   0x0A`" and "`mov ah,BUFFERED_INPUT_FUNCTION_NUMBER`". For people that aren't very familiar with DOS this makes it easier to read (and/or avoids the need for a comment); but for people very familiar with DOS this makes it a little worse (to check if the right number is actually being used they have to check 2 different places instead of one).

Answer (score 1):

Blatantly stolen from [this DOS interrupts table](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah0a).

Read buffered input

`DS:DX` = buffer

`byte [ds:DX]` = buffer length
`byte [ds:DX + 1]` (input) = number of characters in buffer that can be 
recalled
 (output) = number of characters in buffer

buffer starts at `DS:DX + 2`

`10` is the same as `0Ah`

Comment: That's not what that reference tells us! The number of characters in the buffer on exit is reported **on top of** the field that says how many characters were pre-loaded. The inputted characters start at **`DS:DX + 2`**.

Comment: @SepRoland: Not sure how I made that mistake.

Comment: Don't worry, happens to all of us.